# Photo Management on remote server

Tags: photo-management

I am trying to find a way to manage and organize the photos on my NAS. I am using freenas and have a folder with all of my photos in it. I want to be able to manage and organize those photos and find them but can't seem to add that folder to any of the photo managers I have found.

I have used digikam, kphoto, fspot and have made no progress. I have followed several threads to mount that drive using fuse and autofs but when I go to use that folder as the main place for my photos in the software setup for the photo managers it doesn't connect. Says it can't find that file location and then asks me if I want to create it.

Please help. Using Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit late, I know, but maybe it helps others :)

As I see freenas supports NFS, so mount it as an NFS drive! There are many descriptions how to do it, e.g. http://www.markinthedark.nl/news/ubuntu-linux-unix/85-howto-mount-synology-nas-ds211j-to-ubuntu.html.

Then all photo managers should see your NAS as a local folder. Shotwell does it for sure. However, you need to power up your NAS before starting Shotwell :)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. I also think that NFS is not really the right choice in every home setting. It's hard to synchronise the user accounts/uids on all machines and it's not very forgiving on a less than rock-solid network connection for example.